# Do space stations have standardized officer designations for crew?

Tags: nasa, space-station, russia, china

I have some anecdotal information. The ISS has a commander, and I [noticed here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34702/12102) that it had a Flight Engineer, and in [this article](http://ablogaboutnothinginparticular.com/?p=1042) (found [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34569/did-nasa-tell-the-skylab-astronauts-to-stop-running-around#comment108100_34569)) I see that Skylab had a Science Pilot.

Do space stations (US, Russian, Chinese, and International) have standardized officer designations for crew? Are all standard positions always fully "staffed" when astronauts are present?

Comment: Sometimes the ISS has a Science Officer.  https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/news/releases/2002/h02-175.html  My curmudgeonly take on this is that none of it means anything except for the commander.

Comment: @OrganicMarble it seems there must be some kind of designated commander-in-waiting in case the current commander gets a sudden case of appendicitis. Can't have someone just pull an [Alexander Haig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Haig#Reagan_assassination_attempt:_'I_am_in_control_here').

Comment: That's a deorbit three crewmembers case.

Comment: @OrganicMarble maybe it's a different question, and maybe it exists already and has an answer, but an activity that would probably benefit from having a commander

Comment: I hadn't thought about chain of command. It's here though: http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewpr.html?pid=3418  Sadly NASA doesn't publish the ISS flight rules and they are heavily referenced therein.