# Do astronauts aboard ISS notice a change in ISS orientation?

Tags: iss, attitude

The ISS [was rotated by Nauka today](https://www.reuters.com/lifestyle/science/russias-nauka-space-module-experiences-problem-after-docking-with-iss-ria-2021-07-29/). As far as I understand, this took quite some time, i.e. the ISS was not simply rotated by 45 degrees within a few seconds.

I know that the ISS usually [rotates once per orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/why-does-the-iss-rotate-exactly-once-per-orbit) and that [astronauts do notice acceleration (due to boosting)](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/when-the-iss-accelerates-do-the-astronauts-feel-it). But do astronauts notice such changes in orientation like the one Nauka caused? Or the deliberate change in orientation prior to the docking of Nauka?

I imagine that an astronaut who is not holding on to something might notice that the walls seem to rotate around them slowly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No they didn't notice, the acceleration was very slow and the maximum rate of turn was 1/2 degree per second. It took some time to reach that rate. From the [BBC news article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-58021394):

> Nasa tweeted that "the module's thrusters started firing at 12:45pm ET
> (16:45 GMT) inadvertently and unexpectedly, moving the station 45
> degrees out of attitude".
>
> Communications with the ISS crew were lost for several minutes during
> the incident. However. they "really didn't feel any movement" as the
> space station pitched at half-a-degree a second.

If they didn't notice a 1/2 degree per second change they won't notice the regular rotation as it's even less.

Comment: I've just asked a somewhat related question: [What's the farthest an ISS astronaut gets from the station's center of mass during routine activities? At 0.5 °/s what centrifugal effects are there?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54362/12102)